# How to manually render multiple choice field of a ModelForm in Django template?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have this model which has a MultipleChoice country:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user =  models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices= COUNTRY_CHOICES, blank=True)
```

The Modelform is:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=profile_choices.COUNTRY_CHOICES)  #< Not sure about what to put as queryset
    class Meta:
        model= UserProfile
        fields = ( 'name','country')
```

Where:

```
COUNTRY_CHOICES = (
    ('US','US'),
    ('UK','UK'),
    ('EU','EU'),
    ('other', 'other'),
    )
```

I want to style the output so I avoid using built-in ModelForm rendering. Instead my template is:

```
  {% for c in form.country.queryset %}
      <option value="{{c}}">{{c}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
```

But it does not show anything.
I've tried different things but none worked. So left clueless, and appreciate your help.

Comment: What is `profile_choices`?

Comment: @RodXavier when I use `{% for c in form.country.field.choices %}`, as suggested in that answer, I get a menue of object names (not country names).

Comment: You will get a tuple. What you need to do is change your `for` loop to `{% for value, display in form.country.field.choices %}` or you can stick with your for loop and access the choice as `c.0` for the value and `c.1` for the display. Moreover, you don't need a ModelChoiceField for your use case. A ChoiceField will suffice.

Comment: @RodXavier  You are right. Thanks man!